# Is it possible to access enviromentObject variable inside the init?

Tags: swift, environment-variables, swiftui, swiftui-environment, swiftui-state

is it possible to access enviromentObject variable inside the init function in a struct?

```
@EnvironmentObject var socketHandler: SocketHandler


init() {

    print(self.socketHandler.testVar)

}
```

I tried like this but did not get it to work. I got this error:

```
Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type SocketHandler found
```

I have added the enviromentObject to SceneDelegate and can access the variable in my UI.

Answer (score 1):

If you call it in a usual way, like

```swift
let contentView = ContentView().environmentObject(SomeObject())
```

then definitely the answer is NO, because here is what actually done:

```swift
let temp = ContentView() // < called constructor
let contentView = temp.environmentObject(SomeObject()) // call function on variable that 
                                               // just return another different value
```

Comment: I dont really get what you mean

Comment: @JonathanThunberg, I meant that environment object injected *after* view constructor has finished.

Comment: Mhm okay, even after children views?

Comment: @JonathanThunberg, In every view environment objects are injected in the same way - using `.environmentObject` which is called to already constructed value, ie. after constructor. (`init()` is constructor... just in case)